# Composing multicast delegates in C# - should I use operators or Action.Combine?

Tags: c#, delegates, accessor

Reading the documentation I can see that `+` operator can be used to compose/combine delegates of the same type.

In the same way I can see that I can remove a from the composed delegate using the `-` operator.

I also noticed that the `Action` type has static `Combine` and `Remove` methods that can be used to concatenate the invocation lists of two delegates, and to remove the last occurrence of the invocation list of a delegate from the invocation list of another delegate respectively.

```
        Action a = () => Debug.WriteLine("Invoke a");
        Action b = () => Debug.WriteLine("Invoke b");
        a += b;
        a.Invoke(); 

        //Invoke a
        //Invoke b

        Action c = () => Debug.WriteLine("Invoke c");
        Action d = () => Debug.WriteLine("Invoke d");
        Action e = Action.Combine(c, d);
        e.Invoke();

        //Invoke c
        //Invoke d

        a -= b;
        a.Invoke();

        //Invoke a

        e = Action.Remove(e, d);
        e.Invoke(); 

        //Invoke c
```

They appear to produce the same results in terms of how they combine/remove from the invocation list.

I have seen both ways used in various examples on SO and in other code. Is there a reason that I should be using one way or the other? Are there any pit falls? For example - I can see a warning in the line `a -= b;` stating that `Delegate subtraction has unpredictable results` - so should I avoid this by using Remove?

Comment: `Obviously the static methods return a new delegate whilst the accessors don't` Wrong

Comment: "Delegate subtraction has unpredictable results" is a ReSharper warning, and is seems poorly worded. The results are perfectly predictable. They are defined in the C# spec. However, for some users, their mental model of delegate subtraction does not conform to the spec and thus the result is "unpredictable" to them.

Comment: @SLaks - can you explain that further? `a += b` doesn't return a new `Delegate` whilst  `Delegate.Combine(a, b)` clearly does.

Comment: @mike z - yes that is a bit mental...ha...

Comment: @Fraser: Wrong. `a += b` is shorthand for `a = a + b` (just like any other `+=` addition), which clearly does return a new delegate.  (Note that _events_ are completely different)

Comment: Writing `Action.Combine` is misleading (and is contributing to confusing the asker here, I think) when in fact the type `Action` does not declare a member `Combine` but only inherits the `static` member from its (immediate or distant) base class. Therefore, if you use `Combine`, certainly write it as `Delegate.Combine` because this shows where the method resides. However, when C# offers `Action e = c + d;`, this is much nicer to read than `Action e = (Action)Delegate.Combine(c, d);`. Then `Delegate.Combine` can be called explicitly from .NET languages that do not offer any syntax.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The delegate operators (`+` and `-`) are shorthand for the static methods.
There is no difference at all.

`a += b` compiles to `a = (Action)Delegate.Combine(a, b)`

Comment: Many thanks - really the thing that puzzled me was that `a += b` leaves `a` as type `Action` whilst `Delegate.Combine(a, b)` returns a `Delegate` type rather than an `Action` type...

Comment: @Fraser: If you look at the generated IL, you'll see a `castclass` instruction after `Delegate.Combine` for `+=`.  (You can see this in LINQPad)

Comment: ...So - the accessors don't return a `Delegate` type, they return an object of the same type as the two objects being composed (in this case `Action`) whist the static methods always return a `Delegate`. I think I confused the issue by just saying 'delegate' rather than type `Delegate`

Comment: @Fraser: (Note that they're called _operators_, not accessors).  The operators do the exact same thing as the methods; the static methods also return the same type as their operands.

Comment: ah, yes... it was my using `Delegate.Combine` ... rather than `Action.Combine` that threw me. Sorry for the confusion.